# Image directory

Tags: php, image, root

Hello I would like to do a function like "get_template_directory ()" from wordpress
I did this :

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', dirname (__ DIR__, 1) .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "public" .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

  function getImageUri (){echo SITE_ROOT. '/ assets / img';}
```

Example for the logo
"`<img src ="<?php getImageUri ();?>/logo.png">`"

the problem is that the returned url looks like this
"file: /// C: /wamp64/www/mywebsite/public//assets/img/logo.png"

suddenly error (Not allowed to load local resource)

Any idea please?

Comment: You see local url, because you run that in local server, when you will use that on your web domain you will see you website url..

Comment: Step 1: Stop confusing file system paths, and URLs.

Comment: Yes I understood that, but I still need to have the absolute url locally

Answer (score 1):

There're several types of paths:

- A URL path is the convention you use to reach network resources using the HTTP protocol and typically start with `http://` or `https://`, even if the browser decides to hide the prefix.
- A file system path is the convention you use to reach files in your own computer's hard disk. On Windows they typically look like `C:\Program Files\...`.

Just because you call them all "path" and they often look similar it doesn't mean they're the same thing or they're interchangeable.

The `<img>` tag is part of HTML, the core language of the web, so it doesn't use file system paths. You need to compose URL, not file system paths. However the [`__DIR__` magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) retrieves a file system path, which is not what you want.

In your example, `SITE_ROOT` can be as simple as this:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', '/');
function getImageUri()
{
    return SITE_ROOT . 'assets/img';
}
```

... because you can normally omit the protocol, host and port fragments of the URL when already in your site's context.